# Test an integer value to determine if it is odd or even in C++

Tags: c++

I have to write a program to test an integer value to determine if it is odd or even, and make sure my output is clear and complete. In other words, I have to write the output like `"the value 4 is an even integer"`. I was also hinted that I have to check the value using the remainder modulo.

The issue I have is with the `scanf()` function.  I get a syntax error:

> '%=' expected a ')'

How do I fix this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = 0;

    cout << "enter an integer ";
    int scanf(%=2 , &number);

    if (number == 0)
        cout << "the value" << number << "is even";
    else
        cout << "the value" << number << "is odd";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::cin >> number; if (number % 2 == 0) `  ?

Comment: Perhaps this could help https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

Comment: lol the down votes, people are definitely cut throat I am sorry for my ignorance I'm going to try what you guys said though thank you frfr

Comment: A note about `scanf`. It's a really neat, but really dangerous function. It accepts a variable arguments list, and this variability eliminates type checking to make sure you're passing in the correct type and number of arguments. Some compilers have been extended to read the format argument and pass judgement on the fitness of the parameters supplied to it, helping pick off quite a few mistakes that would otherwise slip though.

Comment: I'm grateful I just sorta would like an explanation to this more then just the answer, I could write what I thought about it but it would sound like an unorganized mess of different sources interpretation of the subject. Most of what im here I feel like I need to see, like gears inside a toy car or something you know

Answer (score 1):

You are using `scanf()` incorrectly (read the [`scanf()` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)  on cppreference.com).  The first parameter expects a null-terminated string containing the format to scan, but you are not passing in anything that even resembles a string. What you are passing in is not valid string syntax, per the C++ language standard. That is why you are getting a syntax error.

You need to change this line:

```
int scanf(%=2 , &number);
```

To this instead:

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```

Though, in C++ you really should be using `std::cin` instead for input (you are already using `std::cout` for output):

```
std::cin >> number;
```

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = 0;

    cout << "enter an integer ";
    if (cin >> number)
    {
        if ((number % 2) == 0)
            cout << "the value " << number << " is even";
        else
            cout << "the value " << number << " is odd";
    }
    else
        cout << "the value is invalid";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He asked about a problem with `scanf()`, and people gave him the answer to his homework as well ... :(

Comment: I'm grateful I just sorta would like an explanation to this more then just the answer, I could write what I thought about it but it would sound like an unorganized mess of different sources interpretation of the subject. Most of what im here I feel like I need to see, like gears inside a toy car or something you know

Comment: @ColinCruz I gave you an explanation, what don't you like about it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little dated, however, if you are able to use modern C++ features. You can write a `constexpr` helper function such as this:

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr bool isEven(uint32_t value) {
    return ((value%2) == 0);
}
```

Then in your main function, you can traverse through a loop of N integers and output your display such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
         std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << i << " is " 
                   << (isEven(i) ? "even" : "odd") << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's literally that simple. Here's another nice feature of using the `constexpr` helper function... You can also format your output as such:

```
int main() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
         std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << i << ": " 
                   << std::boolalpha << isEven(i) << '\n';
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you are looking for something that is more efficient than using the modulo operator you can bitwise & with the least significant digit... The code above would then become:

```
#include <cstdint>
constexpr bool isOdd(uint32_t value) {
    return (value&1);
}
```

And using it would be very similar as above, just make sure you reverse the wording in your output to match that from the function being used...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
         std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << i << " is " 
                   << (isOdd(i) ? "odd" : "even") << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Again you can use the `std::boolalpha` manipulator to get this kind of output:

```
int main() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
         std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << i << ": " 
                   << std::boolalpha << isOdd(i) << '\n';
    }
    return true;
}
```